# if (var) vs. if (var != "")

Tags: javascript, html, textbox

Sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Check Text Field Value</title>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <textarea rows="5" cols="35" id="field" oninput="indicate();"></textarea>
    <div id="indicator"></div>
    <script>
        function indicate() {
            var field = document.getElementById('field');
            var indicator = document.getElementById('indicator');
            if (field.value) {
                indicator.innerHTML = 'Some content';
            } else {
                indicator.innerHTML = 'No content';
            }
        }
        indicate();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RainLover/eZaRd/

I want to check if the text field is empty or not. I've seen many questions and answers some using `if (textarea.value)` and some using `if (textarea.value != "")`. Or the following pair:
`if (!textarea.value)` vs. `if (textarea.value == "")`.

I wonder what's the difference between them.

Comment: `if (textarea.value = "")` is a bug. The two other ones are equivalent.

Comment: After edit : the three tests are equivalent. But any search on SO would have told it.

Comment: @dystroy Incidentally, that's why a lot of people make a habit of putting the literal before the variable, as in: `if ("" == some.variable)` or `if (0 == x)`. It looks strange at first, but when you mistype an equal sign you will get a nice error, instead of all hell breaking loose.

Comment: @dystroy: Many thanks for the comments! Just wanted to make sure they are the same in my example. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you just write `if (textarea.value)`, it will return true for all the truthy values of the text area. For all the falsy values it will return false like NaN, undefined, null or ""
In other case `if (textarea.value = "")`, it will return true only if the value of the text area is "".

You should use !! operator to check for both scenarios (undefined and empty) as follows:
 if (!!textarea.value)

Comment: How can the textarea value in my example be null, undefined or NaN? Would you mind giving an example?

Comment: We faced it once. But I am unable to remember the scenario. Other scenario is , if it is unable to find your element, then also it will return undefined like $("#not-found-id").val();